# Script not accepting an argument from config.ini file

Tags: python, configparser

I have developed this python script to run services from a config file.

My config file which is `config.ini`

```
[my-config]
path1 = "/home/asad.javed/stop-services.sh"
path2 = "/home/asad.javed/script.py"
path3 = "/home/asad.javed/getbps.sh ens6f0"
```

My source code file is `testscript.py`

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import configparser
import argparse as ap
import subprocess
import sys
import SIPOps as sip

def get_sipresponse():
        p = sys.path.append("/home/asad.javed/")
        response = sip.ping('172.16.26.77')
        response.get('Status')
        print(response)
        return p, response

def file_reader():
        configParser = configparser.ConfigParser()

        configParser.read('config.ini')
        path1 = configParser.get('my-config','path1')
        path2 = configParser.get('my-config','path2')
        path3 = configParser.get('my-config','path3')
        return path1,path2,path3

def main():
        path1,path2,path3 = file_reader()
        parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', help='start script', action='store_true')
        parser.add_argument('-q', '--stop', help='stop script', action='store_true')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        if args.start and args.stop:
                print("error")
        elif args.start:
                subprocess.call([path1], shell=True)
                subprocess.call([path2], shell=True)
                subprocess.call([path3], shell=True)
        elif args.stop:
                p.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
        file_reader()
        get_sipresponse()
```

The problem I am facing is that for `path3` in config file I am not able to pass the network interface `en6f0`. Can someone guide me on how to pass `ens6f0` as argument to my python script?

Comment: Try changing `subprocess.call([path3], shell=True)` to `subprocess.call(path3.split(" "), shell=True)`.

Comment: Alternatively, `subprocess.call(path3, shell=False)` should also work.

Comment: No Its not working. I tried both..

Comment: ens6f0": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
ens6f0": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
I got this error message when I tried to run with ubprocess.call(path3.split(" "), shell=True).

Comment: Looks like `shell=True` should be used when the input is a string input and `shell=False` should be used for a list. Please try `subprocess.call(path3.split(" "), shell=False)`.

Comment: Now with the above I am getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testscript.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "./testscript.py", line 38, in main
    subprocess.call(path3.split(" "), shell=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 287, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

Answer (score 0):

You can read .ini file arguments on python with "sys.argv" instruction. If you have more than one argument for example: path3 = "/home/asad.javed/getbps.sh ens6f0 arg2 arg3" you just need to specify which one you need like "sys.argv[X]" where X is the position of your argument.

In your python script just try:

yourParameter1 = sys.argv[1]

Happy coding :)

Comment: Where use it? And why?

Comment: Where you need it in your python script. Because you can read .ini file arguments on python with "sys.argv" instruction. If you have more than one argument for example: path3 = "/home/asad.javed/getbps.sh ens6f0 arg2 arg3"   you just need to specify which one you need like "sys.argv[X]" where X is the position of your argument.

Comment: So, maybe you should put this context in your answer for better understanding